# The argument type 'ListOf5' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ListOf5'

Tags: dart

I need to implement an abstract class function, which own a an specific data type. But I need inside my logic layer to make the attribute which is going to be passed as a dynamic data type. But when i Pass it to the function, i am sure that its data type will be as needed. So, i type **(product.value.pickedImages) as ListOf5)** . But it does an Exception.

**The Abstract Class Code Is:**

```
 Future<Either<FireStoreServerFailures, List<String>>> uploadProductImages(
      {required ListOf5<File> images});
```

**The Implementation Code Is:**

```
Future<Option<List<String>>> _uploadImagesToFirestorage() async {
    return await productRepo
        .uploadProductImages(
            images: (product.value.pickedImages) as ListOf5<File>) // Exception
  }
```

**The Exception Is:**

> The argument type 'ListOf5 < dynamic>' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'ListOf5 < File>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast the List from `List<dynamic>` to `List<String>`.
Instead, you should cast each item, using something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<dynamic> a = ['qwerty'];
  print(List<String>.from(a));
}
```

Not sure about the implementation of this ListOf5 though...

Answer (score 0):

The cast `(product.value.pickedImages) as ListOf5<File>` fails.
It fails because `product.value.pickedImages` is-not-a `ListOf5<File>`, but instead of `ListOf5<dynamic>` (which may or may not currently contain only `File` objects, but that's not what's being checked).

Unlike a language like Java, Dart retains the type arguments at run-time(it doesn't do "erasure"), so a `ListOf5<dynamic>` which contains only `File` objects is really different from a `ListOf5<File>` at run-time.

You need to convert the `ListOf5<dynamic>` to a `ListOf5<File>`.

How to do that depends on the type `ListOf5`, which I don't know.
For a normal `List`, the two most common options are:

- `(product.value.pickedImages).cast<File>()`. Wraps the existing list and checks on each read that you really do read a `File`. It throws if you ever read a non-`File` from the original list. Perfectly fine if you'll only read the list once.
- `List<File>.of(product.value.pickedImages)`. Creates a new `List<File>` containing the values of `product.value.pickedImages`, and throws if any of the values are not `File` objects. Requires more memory (because it copies the list), but fails early in case there is a problem, and for small lists, the overhead is unlikely to be significant. If you read the resulting list many times, it'll probably be more efficient overall.

If the `ListOf5` class provides similar options, you can use those. If not, you might have to build a new `ListOf5` manually, casting each element of the existing `ListOf5<dynamic>` yourself.
(If the `ListOf5` class is [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891342/adding-a-new-value-to-a-class-of-list-dart), you can choose to add such functionality to the class).